# Cannot reboot after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 sometimes

Tags: reboot

My laptop: Lenovo V460

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.  Sometimes it fails to reboot (from both terminal and desktop) and just hangs. I see only several points blinking one after another.

My laptop worked well when I was under Ubuntu 12.04. Could anyone explain what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my solution for anybody who meets the same problem.

Under 12.04, I installed bumblebee to switch graphic cards.
It seems that bumblebee causes Ubuntu 14.04 to have this issue.

I removed it `sudo apt-get remove bumblebee*` and my problem is solved.